# Get only some keys of object of objects

Tags: javascript, data-structures, mapping, reduce

I've this object:

```js
const dataset = {
  "2019": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
  },
  "2020": {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 4,
    "c": 6,
    "d": 8
  },
  "2021": {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 11,
    "c": 12,
    "d": 13
  }
}
```

I would like to obtain these two objects:

```js
const obj1 = {
  "2019": {
    "a": 1,
    "c": 3,
  },
  "2020": {
    "a": 2,
    "c": 6,
  },
  "2021": {
    "a": 10,
    "c": 12,
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  "2019": {
    "b": 2,
    "d": 4
  },
  "2020": {
    "b": 4,
    "d": 8
  },
  "2021": {
    "b": 11,
    "d": 13
  }
}
```

So "split" the object in two objects based on some keys of the inner objects.
Here is what I tried:

```js
function pickKeys(dataObj, keys) {
  return Object.entries(dataObj).map(([d, obj]) => {
  return { [d]: _.pick(obj, keys) }
})
}
const obj1 = pickKeys(dataset, ['a', 'c'])
```

The result is:

```js
const obj1 = [
  { '2019': { a: 1, c: 3 } },
  { '2020': { a: 2, c: 6 } },
  { '2021': { a: 10, c: 12 } }
]
```

So almost there but it's not perfect. Which is the better way to do that?

Comment: what is the logic behind separating `a,c` and `b,d`

Comment: No logic, I need to to split the object in that way

Comment: So it's always an object with `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` properties? And you always want `a` and `c` in one object and `b` and `d` in the other object?

Comment: Ultimately you want an object, so when you start with `Object.entries` you'll somehow come back to [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) or [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array with replaced elements, while you want an object.

Since you are already using Lodash you could use [`mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues) to transform the values of an object and return an object instead of an array.

```
function pickKeys(dataObj, keys) {
  return _.mapValues(dataObj, obj => _.pick(obj, keys));
}
```

```js
function pickKeys(dataObj, keys) {
  return _.mapValues(dataObj, obj => _.pick(obj, keys));
}

const dataset = {
  "2019": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
  },
  "2020": {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 4,
    "c": 6,
    "d": 8
  },
  "2021": {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 11,
    "c": 12,
    "d": 13
  }
}

console.log(pickKeys(dataset, ["a", "c"]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do this using combination of `map`, `reduce` methods and one `for...in` loop that will turn array of keys into array of objects. Then you can use array destructuring to get two separate objects.

```js
const dataset = {"2019":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4},"2020":{"a":2,"b":4,"c":6,"d":8},"2021":{"a":10,"b":11,"c":12,"d":13}}

const [a, b] = [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
.map(keys => keys.reduce((r, key) => {
  for (let year in dataset) {
    if (!r[year]) r[year] = {}
    r[year][key] = dataset[year][key]
  }

  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the wanted keys by using the entries of the given object.

```js
const
    dataset = { 2019: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, 2020: { a: 2, b: 4, c: 6, d: 8 }, 2021: { a: 10, b: 11, c: 12, d: 13 } },
    groups = [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']],
    [result1, result2] = Object
        .entries(dataset)
        .reduce((r, [k, o]) =>
            groups.map((group, i) =>
                group.reduce(
                    (q, g) => ({ ...q, [k]: { ...q[k], [g]: o[g] } }),
                    r[i] || {}
                )
            ),
            []
        );

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The next provided example code is [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based, generic but configurable in its usage ...

```js
function createAndCollectSubdata(collector, dataEntry) {

  const { keyLists, subdataList } = collector;
  const [ dataKey, dataValue ] = dataEntry;

  keyLists.forEach((keyList, idx) => {

    const data = subdataList[idx] || (subdataList[idx] = {});
    const subdata = data[dataKey] || (data[dataKey] = {}) ;

    keyList.forEach(key => subdata[key] = dataValue[key]);
  });
  return collector;
}

const dataset = {
  "2019": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
  },
  "2020": {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 4,
    "c": 6,
    "d": 8
  },
  "2021": {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 11,
    "c": 12,
    "d": 13
  }
};
const [

  acSubdata,
  bdSubdata
  
] = Object.entries(dataset).reduce(createAndCollectSubdata, {

  keyLists: [["a", "c"], ["b", "d"]],
  subdataList: []

}).subdataList;

console.log('acSubdata :', acSubdata);
console.log('bdSubdata :', bdSubdata);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```